# Generate cross-platform application

Tags: android, c++, ios, embedded, cross-platform

I have c++ based application that generate executable file for windows. Now I want to generate file for android and IOS.

Should I replace file extension in code only? Or I can be modify code as there is cross-platform mobile development feature in Visual Studio 2015.

**Note: Generated application is a simple user authentication form with wrapped PDF file.**

Comment: exe files are only for windows. Android apps run with java not C++, and in IOS they use Objective C or Swift

Comment: At bare minimum you need to compile. Unless you used something like Qt to help portability, chances are good that you may have to do quite a bit more than that.

Comment: You might be able to use Javascript and HTML5, as there exist ways of running this on all of your platforms.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You'd like to write a portable source code that compiles on Windows, iOS and Android (this is far from being trivial) or write interpreted (byte)code which can run on a virtual machine on those platforms (this is also far from easy).

Each operating system have its own format for executable file format and for system calls (ways for your program to interact with the OS and thus with the hardware). You can't simply rename an executable file for it to be runnable by every system.

An easier way would be to write an web applications, running through the web navigator. Otherwise, I'm afraid you'd have to write three different application, with bit of code reusable though.

Comment: I can't go to web based, any minimum effort to get this task done is required

Comment: I'm sorry, those three platforms are really heterogeneous. You may find a way to write portable-ish code for windows and android with Qt, but iOS is soo restrictive. Unless you control the device and impose it to be jailed-broken, then it's just a fancy BSD.

Comment: Core functionality can be in C/C++ on just about any platform including those named; it's user interface and platform interaction (including how your code gets started up) where you have to deal with uniqueness of the platform.